# How to save multiple time values for timer in preferences in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, preferences

I'm working on timer app using kotlin. My requirement is to save multiple time values in preferences. For that purpose I have made a separate class for preferences.
This is the work done by me.

*In PrefUtil class*

```
private const val ElAPSED_TIME_VALUE_ID = "com.code.kotlin.elapsed_time"
        private var incrementedValue = 0

        fun getElapsedTime(context: Context) : Long {
            val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            return preferences.getLong(ElAPSED_TIME_VALUE_ID , 0)
        }

        fun setElapsedTime(elapsedTime: Long, context: Context) {
            val editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
            editor.putLong(ElAPSED_TIME_VALUE_ID, elapsedTime)
            editor.apply()
        }
```

*On toggle button*

```
btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                startTimer()
                timerState = TimerState.Running
                showStartTime()
                startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                PrefUtils.setStartTimeValue(startingTime, this)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Timer is Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                timer.cancel()
                onTimerFinished()
                elapsedTime()
                PrefUtils.getElapsedTime(this)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Timer is Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

***For saving elapsed time in preferences and then to get from there***

```
private fun elapsedTime() {
        val endingTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val startTime = PrefUtils.getStartTimeValue(this)
        elapsedTime = (-startTime + endingTime)
        PrefUtils.setElapsedTime(elapsedTime, this)
    }
    private fun showElapsedTime() {
        val minut = (PrefUtils.getElapsedTime(this) / 1000) / 60
        val sec = (PrefUtils.getElapsedTime(this) / 1000) % 60
        val elpTime: TextView = findViewById(R.id.elpTime)
        elpTime.text = "Elapsed time: $minut : $sec "
    }
```

*On pressing pause button I want to show saved multiple time values..*

```
fabPause.setOnClickListener {
            timer.cancel()
            timerState = TimerState.Paused
            updateButtons()
            showElapsedTime()
        }
```

Now the problem is that when I close the app after getting one preference value the time value is automatically removed from preferences. On next session it is saved as new.. While I want to save and show multiple time values in multiple sessions. What should I do??? 
Need Your Help.......!

Comment: Well when you close the app you're memory / class instance is going to be gone. You'll need some means of saving to a database or file and read the values back. Android and IOS have hundreds of strategies on how to save and read data back. A simple 'industry' solution is to use Firebase to save your users preferences and read them back if you want to use external services. If you just want it to be usable without internet connection just save to a local file and read it back. a quick google search https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-store-data-locally-in-android-app-717190/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save all the timestamps using the same `ElAPSED_TIME_VALUE_ID` key, you can use e.g. `SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet()`. Or you can concat them to things like "timestamp1:timestamp2" then parse the string manually.